# create a widget in SWT with 2 parents

Tags: java, swt

Is there any way to create a widget in SWT with 2 parents such that same widget appears in both the places? 
For example:

```
Button Source = new Button(composite1||composite, SWT.RADIO);
```

Comment: Why would you want to be able to do that anyway?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SWT controls can only have one parent so you can't do this.

You can change the parent of a control using the `Control.setParent(Composite)` method, but this may not be supported on some platforms so is probably best avoided.